# Efficient method to find nearest datetime's for large dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns, both are datetime instances. The first column is made of measurement timings and the second column is the sum of the first column with a constant offset. E.g assuming a constant offset of 1 gives:

| index | Measurement_time | offset_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.1 | 1.2 |
| 1 | 0.5 | 1.5 |
| 2 | 1.2 | 2.2 |
| 3 | 2.4 | 3.4 |

I would like to find the index of each measurement_time that closest matches the offset_time with the condition that the measurement_time must be smaller than or equal to the offset_time. The solution to the given example would therefore be:

index = [2, 2, 2, 3]

I have tried using `get_loc` and making a mask but because my dataframe is large, these solutions are too inefficient.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to find the indices of closest matches

```
s = df['Measurement_time'].sort_values()
np.searchsorted(s, df['offset_time'], side='right') - 1
```

Result:

```
array([2, 2, 2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Note: You may skip the `.sort_values` part if your dataframe is already sorted on the column `Measurement_time`